# Intelligently handling attributes when fetching an xml text value from XML using PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath, powershell-4.0, xml-attribute

To fetch the value of an XML element in powershell, we can simply write out the path by treating the elemnts as if they were properties of a PowerShell object; i.e. `$xml.RootElement.ChildElement.GrandChild`.

However, if the element we're interested in has an attribute associated, to get the text value we need to drill down to the text node; i.e. `$xml.RootElement.ChildElement.GrandChild.'#text'`.

Sadly when the element doesn't have an attribute, we can't use the text node; i.e. in that scenarion, `$xml.RootElement.ChildElement.GrandChild.'#text'` **does not work**.

```
Clear-Host
$example = [xml](@"
<demo>
    <element attribute='1'>10</element>
    <element>20</element>
</demo>
"@)

"just the element"
$example.demo.element 
"element's text"
$example.demo.element.'#text'
```

I've written a nasty workaround for this, but suspect that's the wrong approach / that PowerShell has a more elegant way to resolve this issue.

My Nasty Workaround:

```
function Get-TextNode {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        $xmlElement
    )
    process {
        if($xmlElement.Attributes.Count -eq 0) {
            $xmlElement
        } else {
            $xmlElement.'#text'
        }
    }
}

$example.demo.element | Get-TextNode
```

Comment: ps. I noticed that adding `$xmlElement.GetType()` to my command shows that the type of the element changes according to whether or not any attributes are present; i.e. if they are it's an `XmlElement`, if there aren't, it's a `String`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SelectNodes` function works around this issue:

i.e.

```
$example.SelectNodes('/demo/element').'#text'
```

or

```
$example.SelectNodes('/demo/element/text()').Value
```

work as expected.

It's also possible to update nodes in this way:

```
Clear-Host

$example = [xml](@"
<demo>
    <x>5</x>
    <element attribute='1'>10</element>
    <element>20</element>
</demo>
"@)

$example.OuterXml
#Result: <demo><x>5</x><element attribute="1">10</element><element>20</element></demo>

$example.SelectNodes('/demo/element/text()') | %{ 
    $_.value = $_.ParentNode.ParentNode.SelectSingleNode('./x/text()').Value  
}

$example.OuterXml
#Result: <demo><x>5</x><element attribute="1">5</element><element>5</element></demo>
```